# TouchableOpacity onPress not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, touchableopacity

I have 3 simple react components-

First the actual view(let us name this screen A)-

```
return(
    <ImageBackground
    ...
    >
       <ScrollView>


          <ChildButton
            onPress={this.someFunction.bind(this)}
           />

       </ScrollView>
    </ImageBackground>
)
```

Then there is the ChildButton component---

```
    return(
    <ChildButton>
       <Button
         style={...someStyleObject}
         onPress={this.props.onPress}
        >

       </Button>

    </ChildButton>
)
```

and then there is Button component ---

```
return (
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.props.onPress}
 >
    {this.props.children}
</TouchableOpacity>

)
```

The main problem here is my onPress is not getting called from screen A, only on Android. It is working fine on iOS. What are the possible causes here?

Note: I've put consoles inside ChildButton and Button component and they are not getting printed.

Comment: Does 'ChildButton' component use itself in render method? `return( <ChildButton>`

Comment: @OleksandrBlyzniuk ChildButton is a functional component whereas Button is a class component.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue when I accidentally imported `TouchableOpacity` from "react-native-gesture-handler" instead of from "react-native". If this is the case for you, change so `TouchableOpacity` is imported from "react-native" and remove the import from "react-native-gesture-handler" and it should work!

Comment: Thank you! Now just hang on a moment while I put on my dunce cap.

Comment: Yeah, hi. It's me again. Guess I should just keep the cap on then. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made that mistake already 5 times and I forget to look for the auto imports every time.

Comment: Hahah wow. Thank you for this. I tried everything before realizing this was the issue. It works on ios which makes it harder to track down

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue when I inherited a RN project in progress. I didn't realize we had this "react-native-gesture-handler" package installed and accidentally let VS Code auto import it.

Always check your imports! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native' 
works fine in both android and iOS


import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
Does not work in android, but works in iOS.
```

So better to user react-native imports.

onPress event is not calling in android if TouchableOpacity imported from react-native-gesture-handler.